# how to format the value in currency format in gridview

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void LineItemGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     Label lbl3 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbltotal");
     if (lbl3 != null)
     {
         lbl3.Text = college.Student.Activity[e.Row.RowIndex].Mark1.ToString();
         total += decimal.Parse(lbl3.Text);
     }
}
```

In the aspx page

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total"  HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-Width="120px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
```

Answer (score 0):

The format string is "c".

```
invoicetransmit.Invoice.LineItem[e.Row.RowIndex].TotalNetAmount.ToString("c");
```

Comment: I tried the above line protected void LineItemGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)     {  Label lbl3 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbltotal");             if (lbl3 != null)             {                 lbl3.Text = college.Student.Activity[e.Row.RowIndex].Mark1.ToString("c");                 total += decimal.Parse(lbl3.Text);             } it gives me an error stating "Input string was not in a correct format."

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void LineItemGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     Label lbl3 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbltotal");
     if (lbl3 != null)
     {
         lbl3.Text = college.Student.Activity[e.Row.RowIndex].Mark1.ToString("c");
         total += decimal.Parse(college.Student.Activity[e.Row.RowIndex].Mark1.ToString());
     }
}
```